# Окончание в причастии

Tags: согласование, причастия, единственное-множественное-число, приложение, род

«Сведения о номинаторе – авторе либо организации, осуществляющие (-щих, -щей) выдвижение произведения на соискание премии».

Какое окончание необходимо в причастии? Множественное число? Либо окончание по слову «организация»?..

Answer (score 3):

Ни ***-щих,*** ни ***-щей*** здесь не подходит. ***Автор либо организация*** – приложение, относящееся к ***номинатору***, который и будет задавать число и род причастию:

*Сведения о номинаторе, осуществляющ**ем** выдвижение...*

На слух исходное предложение, конечно, читается плохо: причастие оторвано от определяемого слова и идёт за сущестительным женского рода. Если такая формулировка устраивает, то на письме лучше поставить скобки:

*Сведения о номинаторе (авторе либо организации), осуществляющ**ем** выдвижение произведения на соискание премии.*

Answer (score 2):

1. **Номинатор** – это тот, кто выдвигает кого-либо или что-либо для участия в конкурсе на получение премии в состав претендентов одной из номинаций.

**Предположим**, что это может быть **конкретное лицо или организация**.  Кстати, **автор произведения не может выдвинуть себя** в качестве номинатора, так что текст желательно уточнить в этом отношении. Возможно, автору там совсем не место.

Тогда можно записать так: *Сведения о **номинаторе** – авторе либо организации, **осуществляющих** выдвижение произведения на соискание премии.*

**Пояснение.** Здесь лучше подойдет **форма мн. числа**, то есть согласование делается по форме (не по смыслу). Согласование с ближайшим  словом не подходит, так как **род** у двух существительных разный.

2. **Предложенный ранее вариант** (со скобками) также представляется корректным, но это зависит от официальной формулировки Положения.
3. **В качестве примера**

ПОЛОЖЕНИЕ о Всероссийской литературной премии имени Фёдора Абрамова

19. Для выдвижения на соискание премии лица, указанные в пункте 18...представляют в организационный комитет следующие **материалы** : 1) книжное и/или журнальное издание произведения в двух экземплярах; 2) письмо о выдвижении на соискание премии, в котором должны содержаться **следующие сведения:** - **сведения о **номинаторе** – организации, осуществляющей** выдвижение произведения на соискание премии...

https://www.aonb.ru/upload/obr/Pologenie%20Chistaya%20kniga%202021.pdf